# Solve trigonometric equation $\sin(2t) = −\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ on interval $[0, 2 \pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following equation on interval $[0, 2 \pi]$:

$$\sin(2t) = −\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

I got $t=\left\{\dfrac{9\pi}{8},\dfrac{15\pi}{8}\right\}$, but website for math assignment  said that it is wrong.

Comment: How did you get your answers?

Comment: rationalize denominator: sin(2t)= -1/sqrt(2)

Comment: Special triangle: 1/sqrt(2)= pi/4

Comment: since 2t=pi/4, t=pi/8

Comment: sin(pi/8) is negative for quadrant III and IV so, pi+pi/8, 2pi-pi/8.

Comment: The smallest value of $2t$ is $5\pi/4$. for the next value of $2t$, add $\pi/2$. There are two more values of $2t$, obtained by adding $2\pi$ to our two values.

Comment: So to find just t the smallest value would be 5pi/8 correct?

Comment: suppose that $\theta=2t$. What is $\theta$'s interval? Having found all the values for $\theta$, convert them back in terms of $t$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin2t=-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=-\sin\frac\pi4=\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)\text{ as }\sin(-x)=-\sin x$$

$$\implies2t=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Now check for even $n=2m$(say) where $m$ is any integer

$$\implies2t=2m\pi-\dfrac\pi4\iff t=\cdots$$

We need $0\le t\le2\pi$

Similarly,  check for odd $n=2m+1$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sin\dfrac{5\pi}4=-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2$, so
$$
\sin2t=-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2\\
\sin2t=\sin\dfrac{5\pi}4\\
2t=(-1)^k\left({\dfrac{5\pi}4}\right)+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=(-1)^k\left({\dfrac{5\pi}8}\right)+\dfrac{k\pi}2
$$
You can easy find that for $k=(0,3,-2,5)$ solutions are $t=\left({\dfrac{5\pi}8,\dfrac{7\pi}8,\dfrac{13\pi}8,\dfrac{15\pi}8}\right)$.